# Ionic Vue 3 application switch tab from another tab

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-composition-api

I have created a ionic vue 3 tabs starter application.
Im trying to to switch tab programmatically from one tab to another

here is my situation

```
// in Tab1.vue page
setup(props, context) {
 function moveToTab3(){
      // here I need the code to switch tab1 to tab3
      // possible to call tabs.select() method here ?
    }
  }

// my Tabs.vue page
<ion-tabs ref="tabs" >
```

I searched in the ionic docs and vue docs to know how to get the parent component from a child component, I have not got a solution yet.
any help is much appreciated, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can absolutely do that programmatic routing provided you have access to Vue-Router because ionic under the hood uses Vue router for navigation and since tabs are top-level navigation you can simply call
`$router.push` OR  `$router.replace` inside of your setup function on button click or bind the tab using `router-link`

Here is the documentation from Ionic related to **Navigation/Routing** [Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/navigation) And
I think this is what you are looking for **Accessing The Ionrouter Instance** [Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/navigation#accessing-the-ionrouter-instance)

=====Update =====

Taken directly from the documentation [Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/navigation#navigating-to-different-routes), As you can see in the template on `Ion-Button` a simple `@click` is used to push the route you wish to navigate, while in script tag `useRouter`is accessed from the core vue-router to get access to the underlying router

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-button @click="() => router.push('/detail')">Go to detail</ion-button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { IonButton, IonContent, IonPage } from '@ionic/vue';
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'HomePage',
    components: {
      IonButton, 
      IonContent, 
      IonPage
    },
    setup() {
      const router = useRouter();
      return { router };
    }
  })
</script>
```

The same link also shows how you use `router-link` on `Ion-Button`

`<ion-button router-link="/detail">Go to detail</ion-button>`

without having to tap into a method.. either way, works...